# Regarding Imageview

Tags: android, animation

Dear All,
         I am new to mobile android platform. I am having 5 sequence of image view how do i animate those images. i.e. 1st should be visible rest should be invisible. Than 2nd should visible rest should be invisible like tha it has to repeatedly do...How can i do...i am using relative layout... Help is appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF what you want is to switch different images (this is how I interpreted your question) check out [ImageSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html)

Or you can manually do it, by switching the image resource of an ImageView by running a Thread or with a Timer for more convenience, but I believe the link above would be easier for you

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use GalleryView. [Example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-example)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand if you want all the images to be in the same image view you need to use [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) 
If you want each image to be displayed in deferent ImageView then you can implement Runnable and its run method set imageview1.setImage(null); and imageview2.setImage(what ever you want) and change the ImageView you set every time according to what you want.
At the end of the run method you should use handler.postAtTime() method to start the runnable again in the next time you want.
note: the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is created at you activity and passed to the runnable in constructor or whatever you want.
I hope this was clear. if not please let me know.

---

edit1
To make several imageView animate then you should implement Runnable as follow

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Animator implements Runnable {

    // handler to register the runnable
    private Handler handler;

    private Activity activity;
    // to know the current imageView that we will assign the current image to
    private int next_image_view;

    public Animator(Handler handler, Activity activity) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.activity = activity;
        next_image_view = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        ImageView first = null;
        ImageView second = null;

        switch (next_image_view) {
        case 0:
            first = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            second = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            break;
        case 1:
            first = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            second = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            break;
        case 2:
            first = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            second = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            break;
        case 3:
            first = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            second = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            break;
        case 4:
            first = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            second = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
            break;
        case 5:
            first = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
            second = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            break;

        default:

            break;
        }

        if (first != null && second != null) {
            first.setBackgroundResource(0);
            second.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
        }

        next_image_view++;
        if (next_image_view == 6) {
            // to start from the beginning again
            next_image_view = 0;
        }

        // here we post this runnable to be running again after 1 sec = 1000 MS
        handler.postAtTime(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 1000);
    }

}
```

and the TestActivity as follow

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.ImageView;
```

public class TestActivity extends Activity{

```
private Animator animator;
private Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.animation_layout);

    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
    handler = new Handler();
    animator = new Animator(handler, this);
    handler.postAtTime(animator, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 1000);
}
```

}

your XML file should contains something with 6 imageViews with the corresponding names.

Comment: i tried with frame by frame animation but could not make it sequetially visible and invisible...can u suggest me any sample code...

Comment: then you want the handler method which iterate on the ImaeViews that you have

Comment: Hai frnd i have used ur activtiy file but i got error as unexpected closing error...is there any error in my xml posted below...plz tell me....

Comment: I can't see you r XML but I used table layout with fixed imageView size so you can notice the movement of the image.

Comment: have you register the activity with its name in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: i finished that animation part.....and now with another doubt...can we implement frame by frame animation when we are taping on android screen...idea plz...

Comment: sorry I don't know and don't have time right now to search. try to post question about that or edit this question and title to allow others to answer you